# Scanning classpath with ant build yields different results

Tags: ant, build, java

I have an Ant Task that scans the entire Java project class path for certain class files.

*The method is preety naive:*

- A File object is created at the root of the search path and then there's a recursive search for class files.
- For each class file, use the CURRENT ClassLoader (this.getClass.getClassLoader) with loadClass() to load the class.
- Check if the class loaded is an instanceOf a certain class.

The weird thing is, that if I run my build in debug-mode with "Separate JRE" chosen in the JRE launch tab, the build takes around 8 seconds.
If I select "Run in the same JRE as the workspace" the build takes around 40 seconds.

My project also includes 10K of class files or so.
In debug mode, pausing the build shows clearly that most of the time is wasted at loadClass().

My guess is that "Separate JRE" somehow causes the build to run with a minimal class-path so the class loading process is faster..? But it doesn't make much sense..

Does anybody have a lead on the subject?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Way the look up works in Eclipse within the same JRE and outside JRE is different. Because, Eclipse holds context and all the applications point to that context and work on it. Verify the java command generated for the two diff. actions, you will come to know difference.

Comment: How do you verify that? Please elaborate..